# How to append NSMutable strings into a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my first question to Stack Overflow. I have been using this site for a while and have used it's resources to figure out answers to my programming questions but I'm afraid I can't find the answer I'm looking for this time.

I've created these five strings:

```
//List five items from the book and turn them into strings

//1 Josh the Trucker
NSString *stringJosh = @"Josh the Trucker";

//2 The Witch from the Remote Town
NSString *stringWitch = @"The Witch from the Remote Town";

//3 Accepting the curse rules "Willingly and Knowingly"
NSString *stringRules = @"Accepting the curse rules, --Willingly and Knowingly--";

//4 Josh's time left to live--Five Days Alive Permitted
NSString *stringFiveDays = @"Josh's time left to live--Five Days Alive Permitted";

//5 The Fire Demon Elelmental    
NSString *stringDemon = @"The Fire Demon Elelmental";
```

Then, I've put them in an array:

```
//Create an array of five items from the book
      NSArray *itemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            stringJosh,
                            stringWitch,
                            stringRules,
                            stringFiveDays,
                            stringDemon,
                            nil];
```

Then, I created this mutable string where I need to loop through the array and append the items to a UIlabel.

```
 NSMutableString *itemsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:
                                  @"itemsArray"];
```

Here's the loop, which displays the items in the console log.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"Book Item %d=%@", i, itemsArray[i]);

}
```

My question is, how do I append these items into the UIlabel?
These functions are in my appledelegate.

In my viewDidAppear function (flipsideViewController) I have:

```
label8.text =""----thats where the looped info needs to go.
```

How do I do this?
I feel I need to put them together and append where the NSLog should be...but how do I transfer that info to the textlabel?

I hope I explained myself.

We haven't done ANY append examples, I guess this is where I need to get answers from the "wild"

This is the wildest coding environment I know so I'm hoping I can find some direction here.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: do you mean you need to connect all these five strings into one and put into UILabel?

Answer (score 4):

Once you have all your strings that you want to concatenate in NSArray you can combine them with single call (with whatever separator you want):

```
NSString *combinedString = [itemsArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

If you need more complex logic you can use NSMutableString to create result you want while iterating array, i.e.:

```
NSMutableString *combinedString = [NSMutableString string];
[itemsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
       [combinedString appendFormat:@"Book Item %d=%@ ", idx, obj];
    }];
```

Note also that it is better to iterate through collections using fast enumeration or block enumeration rather than using plain index-based for loop.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I am familiar with some forms of enumeration, but for lack of a broader knowledge base, it's hard for me to follow your second example.

Comment: in enumerateObjectsUsingBlock method block of code will be called for each object in your array, and you don't have to keep extra variable for index of current object in array like in fast enumeration, so it may be more convenient

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableString *labelText = [NSMutableString string];
int i = 0;
for (NSString *item in itemsArray)
    [labelText appendFormat:@"Book Item %d=%@\n", i++, item];

label8.text = labelText;
```

Answer (score -1):

DO this

UILabel *mainlabel;
mainlabel.text = [origText stringByAppendingString:get];

Add your text to mainlabel.. orig text is mutable string or else in forloop just append array object at index text to label.put above line of code in forloop

Comment: AWESOME....just got off overnight shift....will try these approaches after a few ZZZZzzzz's